# Comparing groups that are impacted to different extent by same truncation

Tags: normal-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution

Say I have results for a running event, where there is a cutoff time that is the same for all participants. I assume the results are normally or log-normally distributed, but truncated at the cutoff time.

To compare results across age or gender, I obviously can't use average or percentiles, as I only know the sample means and variance, and with the same cutoff time for all, it impacts the sample groups to different extent.

How can I make a fair comparison of results between these groups, if I only know the mean and variance of the samples, but not of the populations?

The question is also part of a broader question of how to find the unknown mean and variance of a normally distributet population, if I only know the mean, variance and truncation point of the sample.